# Loading Sequential Files in VB

Tags: vb.net, file

I have written a vb program a few years ago and now as I get started with vb again i am hitting a "snag". With sequential files. I am trying to load a file in to the vb program with the file dialog box.

NOTE:I am using structures

```
Dim FileDialog as new openFileDialog
Dim MyStream as Stream = nothing
Dim FileLocation as string  'this is to save the file location
if( FileDialog.ShowDialog() = DialogResults.OK)Then
FS = new FileStream(FileLocation, FileMode.open, fileaccess.Read)
BF = new BinaryFromatter

While FS.Position < FS.Length 
   Dim temp as unit
    ...'Please note that this is where the file reads the structures data.It is to much code to write in.
```

When I run the program I can create a file and save it with the data in and I can load it with the Dialog box, The problem is when I run the program again and try to load it. It just wont run the file or load it(Remember I created the file with this program and saved)

How do I get this to work?

Comment: How or when do you set the variable `FileLocation`?

Comment: You forgot to close the file and now it's locked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you have closed the file after writing and reading the data the first time, and make sure you are using the correct path (`FileLocation`).

Exit Visual Studio between the first and second times you run the program. If it works then, then you know you are not closing the file properly.

Set a breakpoint at the `new FileStream` assignment and check the value of `FileLocation`. Is it the same as it was when the file was written?

Check the error message, if there is one, and see if that tells you anything.